# Download zip from github and run npm install in root

Tags: lightweight-charts

Any tips on how to resolve this? I am wanting to download the repo so I can make a modification.

When I open the unzipped folder in vscode and run npm install in the root I receive this error.

```
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.

> lightweight-charts@4.0.0 postinstall
> npm run install-hooks


> lightweight-charts@4.0.0 install-hooks
> node scripts/githooks/install.js

It seems that it isn't a git repo. Did you use git to clone the repo? Skip installing git-hooks

added 654 packages, and audited 655 packages in 26s

154 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the error since you didn't clone the repo but instead downloaded it as a zip file. You will still be able to build the library.

I would recommend reading the BUILDING.md file if you are getting started with developing for the library.

The git hooks are only used when creating a new commit, at which stage it will run some checks to ensure that the code passes a few linter rules.